# Home button within app

Tags: android, android-navigation

I want to create a "home" button that will bring the user back to the "Home" in my app from whatever activity they are in at the time. I have overridden the action bar so I won't be able to use one. My problem is that when

```
Home → A → B
```

I want to press the home button to return to Home. Originally I had the home button simply `finish()` the activity but in this case that will return me to A. Is there a way to do what I'm attempting?

Just to clarify this is an `ImageButton` on screen, not the hardware home button on the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Intent-Flag` [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

If you don't have many `Activities` then you can simply create an `onClick` in each that is something like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

this flag will take you back to the "Home" `Activity` and clear all others off of the stack

If you have many `Activities` then it may be easier to create a base `Activity` from which to extend all others and include the home button functionality inside that base `Activity`

Comment: I already had a base activity for the custom action bar, so I did what you suggested but I needed to override the onClick method for the home button on the home screen itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have your Image Button create an intent to start your home screen activity, assuming this is what you were looking for. within the OnClick of the button, generate an intent, and startActivity(intent)